# Validate time formatted as 1:00:00 with regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

i work with time additional for jquery validation plugin.

```
$.validator.addMethod("time24", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}$/.test(value);
}, "not valid time format.");
```

this worked Only with this time format:

```
00:00:00
01:00:00
```

But My Time format is:

```
0:00:00
1:00:00
```

Comment: @squint:http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js

Comment: No, I'm saying put a `?` after the `[01]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this regular expression:

```
/^([01]?\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}$/
```

The sub-expression `[01]?\d|2[0-3]` will accept `0`, `1`, ... `9`, `10`, ..., `22`, `23` **and** `00`, `01`, ... is that what you want or do you *not* want leading zeros for the hour? In that case use:

```
/^(1?\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){1,2}$/
```

Comment: i found this from original website: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/additional-methods.js